# Only the Select Portion of Query as Variable to be used multiple times

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, select

I have a set of queries that use the same Select portion of the queries with different joins, Where clauses, etc. below the Select portion. The Select portion is long and since I have to run version of this query close to 30 times, whenever I have to make a change, I have to make that change 30 times. Is there a way to capture just the Select portion of these queries as a variable and call that variable each time? This process is very cumbersome, so if I were able to do this for the Select portion and most of the Where clauses could be condensed into about 5 distinct groupings, that would be wonderful, but I have no idea of how to do it. Here's a simple example of what I'm looking for:

```
DECLARE @TestSelect varchar(max) = (SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, ..., Field 22);

@TestSelect
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.id = Table2.id
```

Is this possible using tsql? And if not using tsql, what would be the best vehicle for this, because as these steps are being run, I am inserting the results into another table.

Comment: You must use dynamic sql and that is not even a valid varchar(max) assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to build your query in a string and then use `sp_executesql` to run the dynamic query. For example:

```
DECLARE @TestSelect varchar(max)
DECLARE @TestQuery varchar(max)

SET @TestSelect = '(SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, ..., Field 22)'
SET @TestQuery = @TestSelect + ' FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @TestQuery
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not think of using a second variable. Rather simple solution. Very much appreciated.